# Pivot Table Count is Zero

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot-table

I have a table of employees that may have 0 or 1 license types assigned. When I do my pivot my count returned is 0 for all license types.

Count / Group By Query

```
SELECT SHORTNM, Count(e.EmployeNumber)
FROM suprkron.EMPLOYEE_LICENSE_VW e
    INNER JOIN LICENSETYPE l ON l.LICENSETYPEID = e.LicenseID
    AND ACTIVESW = '1'
GROUP BY SHORTNM
```

Count / Group By Query Results

| SHORTNM | License Count |
| --- | --- |
| Workforce_Manager | 245 |
| Workforce_Timekeeper_Employee | 2531 |
| Workforce_Professional_Employee | 2522 |

Detail Query

```
SELECT SHORTNM, e.EmployeNumber
FROM suprkron.EMPLOYEE_LICENSE_VW e
INNER JOIN LICENSETYPE l ON l.LICENSETYPEID = e.LicenseID
AND ACTIVESW = '1'
```

Detail Query Results

| SHORTNM | EmployeNumber |
| --- | --- |
| Workforce_Timekeeper_Employee | 1 |
| Workforce_Professional_Employee | 1 |
| Workforce_Timekeeper_Employee | 2 |
| Workforce_Professional_Employee | 2 |
| Workforce_Professional_Employee | 3 |
| Workforce_Manager | 3 |
| Workforce_Timekeeper_Employee | 3 |

Pivot Table Query

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT SHORTNM, e.EmployeNumber, e.EmployeeName
        FROM suprkron.EMPLOYEE_LICENSE_VW e
            INNER JOIN LICENSETYPE lON l.LICENSETYPEID = e.LicenseID
            AND ACTIVESW = '1') t
PIVOT (  Count  (SHORTNM)
FOR EmployeNumber in ([Workforce_Manager],[Workforce_Mobile_Employee], 
                      [Workforce_Timekeeper_Employee],[Workforce_Professional_Employee], 
                      [Workforce_Mobile_Manager])) as pVT
```

Pivot Table Query Results

| EmployeeName | Workforce_Manager | Workforce_Mobile_Employee | Workforce_Timekeeper_Employee | Workforce_Professional_Employee | Workforce_Mobile_Manager |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Emp1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Emp2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Emp3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Comment: But, it's SHORTNM that contains e.g. `[Workforce_Manager]`, yet your query claims to SQL Server that `EmployeNumber` contains it (you said `FOR EmployeNumber in ([Workforce_Manager]` -> EmployeNumber is never 'Workforce_Manager')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nominate the correct column for the pivot

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT SHORTNM, e.EmployeeName
        FROM suprkron.EMPLOYEE_LICENSE_VW e
            INNER JOIN LICENSETYPE lON l.LICENSETYPEID = e.LicenseID
            AND ACTIVESW = '1') t
PIVOT (  Count  (SHORTNM)
FOR SHORTNM in ([Workforce_Manager],[Workforce_Mobile_Employee], 
                      [Workforce_Timekeeper_Employee],[Workforce_Professional_Employee], 
                      [Workforce_Mobile_Manager])) as pVT
```

The pivot for clause should be read as `FOR column_with_values IN ([this],[list],[of],[values],[formatted],[like],[columns])` - the values from your `SHORTNM` column become the columns in the query output, so you have to make sure that `([this],[list],[of],[values],[formatted],[like],[columns])` is a list of values that actually are encountered in `SHORTNM`

Comment: Made that change along with COUNT (EmployeNumber) and I'm now getting count values.

Comment: @Lionel - if this answered your question, remember to mark it as the answer so the poster gets credit.

Comment: (And that it shows green on the dashboard so other people know you. Found your answer and they can direct their time towards people still looking for help)